# Change content of div onclick with Ajax

Tags: ajax, onclick

I want to change the content the div named john to the output from the php file when an image is clicked. I'm sure it's simple but I can't find an example that fits. Here's my code:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
                var ajaxRequest;
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                        document.getElementById("john").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                ajaxRequest.open("GET", "test.php", true);
                ajaxRequest.send(null); 
            }
```

html

```
<img class='cross' src='images/cross.png' onclick="ajaxFunction();">
<div id='john'>john</div>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it with the code below. This code also returns the ID of the element after getting "hello" from the php file.

```
<script language="javascript">
            function calldislike(str){
                if (str==""){
                  document.getElementById("john").innerHTML="";
                  return;
                  }
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("john").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>

<img src='images/cross.png' onclick="calldislike(this.id);" id='3'>
<div id='john'>john</div>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo "hello".$_GET["q"];  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you've got a syntax error with your javascript. Your trying to get the `responseText` from `xmlhttp` but your `XMLHttpRequest` is stored in  `ajaxRequest`

Try this

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status==200){
                document.getElementById("john").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "test.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good catch with the 'xmlhttp' but I've tried your code and it still isn't responding to clicks.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest for cross browser/version, use:

```
var ajaxRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
```

and then,

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var re = "nothing";
    try {re = new window.XMLHttpRequest();} catch(e1) {};
    try {re = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0");} catch(e) {};
    try {re = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");} catch(e2) {};
    try {re = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} catch(e3) {};
    try {re = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");} catch(ex) {};
    if (re != "nothing") {return re;}
    else {return null;};
};
```

as well as changing it to

```
ajaxRequest.responseText();
```

Comment: Thanks. Only 3% of my visitors seem to use old versions of IE, so for now I'm just focused on getting it to work at all, but I suppose it wouldn't hurt to sort that out when I've got the thing working.